# Making SWIG understand char** for using it in Java

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have following three files:

sab1.hpp:

```
class CRectangle 

{
    int x, y;

public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    void print(char **db);
    int area ();
};
```

sab1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sab1.hpp"
using namespace std;

int CRectangle::area () 
{
    return (x*y);
}

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) 
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

void CRectangle::print(char **db) 
{
    cout <<db[0];
}

int main () 
{
    CRectangle rect;
    char *a[] = {"Hi", "bye" }  ;

    rect.set_values (3,4);
    cout << "area: " << rect.area();
    rect.print(&a[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

sab1.i  :

```
%module Rec
%{
/* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
#include "sab1.hpp"
%}
class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    void print(char **db);
    int area ();
};
```

I create various intermediary file using the following usual commands:

1) swig -c++ -java sab1.i

2) g++ -fpic -c sab1.cpp sab1_wrap.cxx -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/include/ -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/include/linux/

Then I create a shared library using this: g++ --shared sab1.o sab1_wrap.o -o libegs.so

Then I create a following Java file for accessing the functions of the C++ class:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("egs");
        CRectangle a = new CRectangle();
        a.set_values(4,5);
        System.out.println(a.area());
        a.print("Hi");
    }
}
```

When I compile the Java File (javac -classpath . Test.java ), I get the following error:

```
Test.java:17: print(SWIGTYPE_p_p_char) in CRectangle cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)  a.print("Hi");
 ^
```

So, how can I make the Java code understand the char ** variable? I have tried creating typemaps in the SWIG interface file (sab1.i) but I'm not able to correctly figure it out.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: A Java String is not a `**char`.

Comment: I'm not a Pythoner (just used SWIG with Perl) but if you post the typemap code you tried I might be able to point out where you went wrong with it.

Comment: @Oktalist This is one of the typemap I found online: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/swig/swig-8/Lib/java/various.i
I tried it but I didn't know the proper approach. And I also find this resource in the SWIG documentation itself: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#converting_java_string_arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%module Rec
%include "various.i"

%apply char **STRING_ARRAY { char **db }

%include "sab1.hpp"
```

The file `various.i` which you linked to should work this way, just put it somewhere where SWIG can find it, in your project include directory or SWIG include path.

Using `%include` instead of `#include "sab1.hpp"` means we shouldn't have to copy the definition of classes we want to wrap. The `%apply` directive applies the typemap from `various.i` to all arguments of `char**` type with the name `db`. If there are other argument names you want to wrap, add them like this:

```
%apply char **STRING_ARRAY { char **db, char **foo, char **bar }
```

If you just want to wrap *all* argument of type `char**` (unsafe!), simply omit the name:

```
%apply char **STRING_ARRAY { char ** }
```

As your C++ code expects the array to contain 2 strings, then as long as you pass an array of 2 or more `String`s from Java, it should be fine. The typemap will add a third null pointer to the array, but your C++ code won't notice. If you pass an array with fewer than 2 `String`s, you will likely crash your C++ code.

If any of the C++ functions you are wrapping also *returns* an array of strings, then you are in trouble. SWIG will attempt to convert those back into Java arrays, but may crash when it looks for a third element in the array (it will keep looking for elements until it finds a null pointer). If you don't mind discarding the return value, you can do this:

```
%module Rec
%include "various.i"

%typemap(jni)     char **db = char **STRING_ARRAY;
%typemap(jtype)   char **db = char **STRING_ARRAY;
%typemap(jstype)  char **db = char **STRING_ARRAY;
%typemap(in)      char **db = char **STRING_ARRAY;
%typemap(freearg) char **db = char **STRING_ARRAY;
%typemap(javain)  char **db = char **STRING_ARRAY;

%include "sab1.hpp"
```

This will only apply the parts of the typemap that deal with input arguments.

Comment: The codes I showed was just an example. The real code has many char ** and char *[] in it. I want to make my Java code pass values using String[] if possible. There is no reason of rewriting the definition of CRectangle in sab1.i. I'm just a beginner in SWIG.

Comment: So it is actually an array of pointers to null-terminated strings. That's not what your example says. How does the function you are wrapping know how many strings there are? Is the outer array also null-terminated?

Comment: In the C++ code, it is array of pointers to null terminated Strings. I cannot understand what you mean by outer array. Meanwhile, these two links:1)http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/swig/swig-8/Lib/java/various.i 2)http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#converting_java_string_arrays seem to address the problem I'm facing with although I'm not able to figure it out. I just want to remove the syntax error which I'm getting now. I can modify the C++ files later, if i can figure out how I can pass java String or String[] to that C++ code using SWIG wrapper.

Comment: About outer array, I mean this: when the C++ code receives the array of strings, and iterates over the array, how does it know when it's reached the end of the array? This is crucial for the SWIG wrapper to know how to convert it from Java into something the C++ code can use.

Comment: Well the array of string has a size of 2.

Comment: Now that I know what your question really was, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Great :) If my answer was correct, please click on the tick to the left of it, under the up/down vote buttons, to "accept" the answer. If not, you could explain how you got it working, if you want to.

Comment: @Oktalist I'm trying to return an array of strings from C to Java. Your example sends it from Java to C, and it works for me, but can I modify it for the other direction ? I don't understand the `typemap(argout)` in `various.i`